# Linking time "undefined reference to " errors

Tags: c, makefile, variables, extern, undefined-reference

I'm having a hard time writing makefiles. I have experience in using the `extern` variables, when I build the project without using makefiles I get absolutely no errors and I can run the program. But from the time I wrote the makefile to build the project, I'm getting `undefined reference to` errors.

I have more than 3 files with me but, for simplicity's sake I will make use of 3 files here to explain the setup.

```
/************Project********/
/* main.c */
int x;
main()
{
...

}

/* File1.c*/
extern int x;
fn1()
{
 ...
 }

/* File2.c*/
extern int x;
fn2()
{
 ...
 }
/*******************************/
```

Upon using the makefile I get `undefined reference to` errors during the linking time pointing to the File1.c and File2.c?

Am I making any mistake which the eclipse fixes on its own(when makefile is not used) and which surfaces when I use makefile?

My final makefile looks like this -

OBJ1 = algorithm/main.o algorithm/File1.o algorithm/File2.o

```
all: final

final: main.o algorithm/File1.o algorithm/File2.o
 @echo "Linking - making Final"
 $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ1)
```

Comment: In your Makefile the "final" rule depends on main.o but then you link against algorithm/main.o. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discrepancy in your Makefile. Your `final` target depend on `main.o`, whereas you give `$(OBJ1)` to the linker, which includes `algorithm/main.o`.

Comment: Ya right, I missed it totally. now I'm able to build. My head had gone fuzzy trying to locate where the problem might be. Thanks a lot.